# Issue with printer installation using GPP and printer separator file "pcl.sep"

Tags: group-policy, printer

We have a Kyocera CS 5551 ci printer that is shared on a server.  The shared printer is configured to use the standard pcl.sep separator file and it has always worked.  About 4 or 5 months ago if not earlier (possibly before my time in this environment) the printer no longer gets installed on client computers when "group policy preferences" is applied because the separator file is considered to be invalid.

Below are the details:

```
Point and Print Restrictions is Disabled.

The pc.sep file is inside the following directory on the server:
C:\Windows\System32\spool\SepFiles\XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX


pcl.sep file contains the following, and it is on a Server 2016 system where the shared printer resides.

\

\H1B\L%-12345X@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCL

\H1B\L&l1T\0

\M\B\S\N\U

\U\LJob : \I

\U\LDate: \D

\U\LTime: \T

\E
```

When group policy runs, the printer should get installed on Win 7 Pro x64 clients but it doesn't.

It fails to install the printer and the following error in the Application log shows up on the client PC:

```
Source: Group Policy Printers

Event ID: 8192

Level: Error

User: SYSTEM
Task Category: (2)

The user 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' preference item in the Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80070707 The specified separator file is invalid.' See trace file for more details.
```

I enabled trace logs and the same error shows up on the client PC:

```
2019-04-09 16:07:58.440 [pid=0x1b8,tid=0xc08] Error creating TCP/IP printer connection [ hr = 0x80070707 "The specified separator file is invalid." ]

2019-04-09 16:07:58.440 [pid=0x1b8,tid=0xc08] Properties handled. [ hr = 0x80070707 "The specified separator file is invalid." ]

2019-04-09 16:07:58.445 [pid=0x1b8,tid=0xc08] Completed class <PortPrinter> - xxx.xxx.xx.xxx. [ hr = 0x80070707 "The specified separator file is invalid." ]

2019-04-09 16:07:58.445 [pid=0x1b8,tid=0xc08] Error suppressed. [ hr = 0x80070707 "The specified separator file is invalid." ]
```

When I manually install the printer on the Win 7 client, it installs without any issue.  This is while the sep file is still included with the shared printer.

If I remove the sep page file from the shared printer then group policy is able to install the printer on the client.

I am not sure why it is considering the file to be invalid.  Replacing the file has made no difference.

I know a few years ago security update KB3170455 was causing issues with printers and group policy, but this is not the issue in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the separator file "pcl.sep" is to force the printer. Below are the steps you can follow to complete your printer configuration using the serator file.

• On your PC, go to the Start menu and open the Settings window.

• Next, click on the Printers options to move forward.

• After that, right-click on a printer and choose the Properties option.

• And then click on the Separator Page button.

• Now, you have to enter the path and file name of the separator page file and select OK.

• Select the OK option once again to close the printer setup process.

In addition, the GPP method will be used to complete the printer installation process.

• Begin by expanding the printer server on the screen.

• Then, choose the printer server from your screen.

• Next, select the printer option.

• Now, look for your printer device and right-click on it.

• Furthermore, select the option Deploy With Group Policy.

•Henceforth, click on the Browse option and choose the GPO to associate with the printer.

• Now, the printer installation process will be complete.

If you are facing any problem with the printer installation process using GPP and printer